# Remove Key Object from Array - Angular 5

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5

I want to know how can we create `const` object variable with array, in which when we add item it should not contain index object.

e.g.

```
const estimateData = {
  'customerId': customerId,
  'vehicleInformation': {},
  'datalines': []
};
```

Here, When I add items in `datalines`, it always comes with `key-value` pair like below.

```
  "datalines": [
    0 : {
      "lineNumber": 1,
      ...
    },
    1 : {
      "lineNumber": 2,
      ...
    }
  ]
```

Because of this my webservice returns exception with error like

```
error: "Bad Request"
exception: "com.alldata.estimator.exceptions.BadRequestException"
message: "unknown dataline type 0"
path: "/estimator/estimates/211204"
```

So my question is how can I remove that 0,1 indexes so my request can be passed successfully and data can be approved. I have tried to add data via `push`, reassigning array, forEach loop but nothing worked.

```
  // I am trying to add data in array by following methods, but nothing works. 
  this.selectedEstimate.datalines.forEach((lineItem: ILineItem) => {
    estimateData.datalines.push(lineItem);
  });
  // estimateData.datalines = this.selectedEstimate.datalines;
```

I have also tried to parse data from JSON, but not worked.

Please let me know where is the issue and how can I solve this. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

Stringify your `estimateData` before sending to the server.

Use the below code:-

```
JSON.stringify(estimateData)
```

```js
const a = {
  'customerId': 1,
  'vehicleInformation': {},
  'datalines': []
};
a.datalines.push({age: 1});
a.datalines.push({age: 2});
a.datalines.push({age: 3});
a.datalines.push({age: 4});

// open browser console to check response
console.log(a);
console.log(JSON.stringify(a));
```

**Please open the browser console to look at the indexes getting printed.**

Comment: I already have tried. Stringify is not an option. webservice will only accept json.

Comment: Send `Content-Type` as `application/json` in the headers of your request and the data in stringified format.

Comment: Create a stackblitz then. And yes, the data travels as string over the internet and you have to specify the Content-Type in the headers to tell the format of the data.